# Invalid Operation Error while compiling Lapack Fortran files with LF Fortran in VS2013

Tags: c#, .net, fortran, lapack, blas

I am trying to compile LAPACK Fortran files with LF Fortran compiler in Visual STudio 2013 to create .NET DLL.

I have succesfully compiled BLAS package, which is a dependency for LAPACK.

But in compiling LAPACK files, I am getting "Invalid Operation" for the statement:

```
CALL CLA_GBRFSX_EXTENDED( PREC_TYPE, TRANS_TYPE, N, KL, KU,
$           NRHS, AB, LDAB, AFB, LDAFB, IPIV, COLEQU, C, B,
$           LDB, X, LDX, BERR, N_NORMS, ERR_BNDS_NORM,
$           ERR_BNDS_COMP, WORK, RWORK, WORK(N+1),
$           TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N),
$           RCOND, ITHRESH, RTHRESH, UNSTABLE_THRESH, IGNORE_CWISE,
$           INFO )
```

I have checked the types of arguments with the ones in the subroutine CLA_GBRFSX_EXTENDED. They all same, but except the return value of "TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)" statement.

I have define a variable as

```
COMPLEX Y_TAIL_ATE(1:2*N)
```

and filled it as

```
Y_TAIL_ATE = TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)
```

And called the subroutine as

```
CALL CLA_GBRFSX_EXTENDED( PREC_TYPE, TRANS_TYPE,  N, KL, KU,
$           NRHS, AB, LDAB, AFB, LDAFB, IPIV, COLEQU, C, B,
$           LDB, X, LDX, BERR, N_NORMS, ERR_BNDS_NORM,
$           ERR_BNDS_COMP, WORK, RWORK, WORK(N+1),
$           Y_TAIL_ATE,
$           RCOND, ITHRESH, RTHRESH, UNSTABLE_THRESH, IGNORE_CWISE,
$           INFO )
```

Now, compiler gives the same error for

```
Y_TAIL_ATE = TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)
```

I understood that problem is

```
TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)
```

Since, my knowledge is about c#, I cannot figure out the solution. But my c# code has to use LAPACK, and I have to solve this problem.

Is there any solution idea?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: How exactly looks the code you are compiling and how exactly the error message looks like?

Comment: The screen capture of the project in VS2013 and error messages is at this link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2lAUX8zuUudMllqVGxURV9TTXc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems is that the expression

```
TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)
```

returns a rank-1 array of complex numbers with `N` elements -- that's what the argument `N` specifies.  Then, the assignment

```
Y_TAIL_ATE = TRANSFER (RWORK(1:2*N), (/ (ZERO, ZERO) /), N)
```

attempts to assign an `N` element array to a `2*N` element array and Fortran won't do that.  The fact that `RWORK` has `2*N` (real) elements is irrelevant to the size of the result of the `TRANSFER` when the size (`N`) is provided as it is here.

Fortran will assign a scalar to an array and will do single-statement assignment of two arrays of the same shape.  But it won't let you write an assignment with different shape arrays on left- and right-hand sides

I know nothing of `CLA_GBRFSX_EXTENDED` and I merely suppose that the compiler is also spotting a mismatch of dummy and actual arguments in the first version of your code.